# Documentation for C# LINQ query patterns

Tags: c#

I have found a few examples online such as the following identity mondad, in which the query syntax is used in a completely different way when the SelectMany extension method is created.

Where can I find documentation on which query syntax maps to their extension method counterparts? In my example below, `from x in ...` maps to a SelectMany(), and also a certain overload of SelectMany(). I'd like to know about all of the LINQ query syntax extension method translations.

```
void Main()
{
    var r = from x in 5.ToIdentity()
        from y in 6.ToIdentity()
        select x + y;

        r.Dump();
}

class Identity<T>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public Identity(T value) { this.Value = value; }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static Identity<T> ToIdentity<T>(this T value)
    {
        return new Identity<T>(value);
    }

    public static Identity<V> SelectMany<T, U, V>(this Identity<T> id, Func<T, Identity<U>> k, Func<T,U,V> s)
    {
        return s(id.Value, k(id.Value).Value).ToIdentity();
    }
}
```

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2008/01/11/the-marvels-of-monads.aspx)

Comment: does this not answer your question http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx

Comment: See also: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx

Comment: Question has been updated to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [summary](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx) by Jon Skeet.

If I had to eyeball it, your query syntax should translate to the following method syntax:

```
var r = 5.ToIdentity().SelectMany(x =>
        6.ToIdentity().Select(y =>
            x + y));
```

The call to `SelectMany` is because you are selecting from two sources and expecting a single sequence of output.

EDIT: Swapped `Select` and `SelectMany`.

Comment: That's correct. I'm after documentation stating that `from x in y` translates to SelectMany() and which overloads of SelectMany() matters. But I'm not just after SelectMany() but all of the query syntax translations.

Comment: For that, I would check the link.